# How can I calculate a formula within a field returned by a query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
Select table1.column1, table2.column1, calcuate(table1.column2) as result
from table1, table2
where table1.id = table2.fkid
```

Say table1.column2 is a varchar and the value is "=table1.column1*table2.column1". I want my query to actually calculate that formula rather than return the text. Thoughts?

Comment: You'll need to use some [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) to pull that off.

Comment: I strongly discourage you to use this method. Database is for CRUD. Anything other should be performed in the application.

Comment: I don't think that's possible in T-SQL (or any other SQL dialect I know).

Comment: I don't think there is a way of doing this in T-SQL, without using dynamic SQL. And even then, I think there would be a better method of achieving the results you need. It might be worth posting up more about your situation, to see if there is an overall better solution.

Comment: You could implement a complete expression parser/evaluator in a CLR function.  It would have some difficulty finding the arguments needed to perform the evaluation.

Comment: With this setup, the formula does not have to be the same for each row returned so if you are thinking dynamic SQL would pull this of you should be prepared from some very nasty stuff. Could probably be solved by generating a query where you make one query for each formula used and then concatenate those queries together using `union`.

Comment: @Oybek That raises a valid question. I'm using SSRS, can I calculate the formula there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is nothing like the JavaScript evaluate in SQL. If you only have a few formulas you can try a CASE switch in your SQL.
But in general you maybe should rethink your Architecure - SQL Statements like that are hard to maintain if you have changes. (And you should always expect changes...)

Example:

```
Select 
  a.column1, 
  b.column1, 
  CASE 
    WHEN b.column2 = 'Multiply' THEN a.column1 * b.column1
    WHEN b.column2 = 'Divide' THEN a.column1 / b.column1
    ELSE 0
  END
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.id = b.fkid
```

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL, you have the EXEC command, but in MySQL, you don't have it.
You have 2 options:

- Create a first query that extract your formula, then build a query dynamically ( may I raise the a warning about security / SQL Injection )
- Create a stored procedure: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,152150,152161#msg-152161